# How Supreme deity and Demon king work together?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In episode 10 of season 3, we see that Meliodas and Elizabeth are fighting against Demon king and Supreme deity.
As demon clan and goddess clan are enemy, also Meliodas and Elizabeth were sinned and punished for helping each other and betraying respective clans.

So my question is how come for punishing them both the supreme being are working together at same time at same place.

Comment: I feel compelled to replicate a highly voted comment I found on reddit: The Demon King and Supreme Godess are dating and are afraid of the young couple to steal their flair.